# Codeigniter number of rows in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a model where I select the proper data from database as below:

```
<?php
    class vacancies extends CI_Model{

        function vacancies()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_vacancies_vac WHERE active_vac = 1 AND end_vac >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_vac DESC");

            if($query->num_rows() >= 1){
                foreach($query->result() as $row){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
        }

    }
```

and a controller to handle this data before sending to view as below:

```
function index()
{
    //check if there any available vacancies

    $this->load->model('vacancies');
    $data['vacancies'] = $this->vacancies->vacancies();
    // then i load the views here 
 }
```

What I need to do, is to know the total number of returned rows here in the controller so I can send the number to the view to use it later.

When using active records I used to use this line of code:

```
$data['num_rows'] = $$data['vacancies']->num_rows();
```

How can I define it in my case?

Comment: I don't get it, you are retrieving that same number already in your code? ( `if( $query->num_rows() >= 1){` )

Comment: your question is how to count the size of an array? google 'php size of array' ;)

Comment: also, that line of code, do you understand what it was doing?

Comment: define a count(*), * in the SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The num-rows(); only works if you're still working on your "query part" in your model. It reffers to the DB object.
You already returned the data.
Try this:

```
 $data['num_rows'] = count($data['vacancies']);
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP to the rescue. Since your model method returns an array, you get the total number rows by [a simple count() call](http://php.net/count).

So, for example,

```
$this->load->model('vacancies');
$data['vacancies'] = $this->vacancies->vacancies();
$data['number_of_vacancies'] = count($data['vacancies']);
```

Comment: Darn, should've refreshed before answering.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an array from the model, so in the controller you can use PHP's count() function:

```
$data['num_rows'] = count($data['vacancies']);
```

There's also a problem with your model, the function will not return an array if there are no results, which could cause problems if you treat it like an array later on. You should add an initialization for $data before the if statement, and then always return even an empty array:

```
function vacancies()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ecc_vacancies_vac WHERE active_vac = 1 AND end_vac >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_vac DESC");

    $data = array();
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you out:

```
if($query->num_rows()!==0){
   return $query->result_array();
}else{
   return 0;
}
```

Return 0 and make an if else statement in the view

```
if($result!=0){
   // No results found
}else{
   // Do something
}
```